# e.preventDefault() not disabling the menu

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener on my canvas which im trying to disable the right click menu as I want to use it for scrolling around the canvas with but my `preventdefault()` does not seem to stop the menu appearing.

This is what i have: **http://jsfiddle.net/zd2042xv/**

And the code :

```
function handle(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //disable menu
    output.innerHTML = 'Button Number: '+e.button;
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',handle,false);
```

Have i misunderstood how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding "oncontextmenu="return false"" to the Canvas will disable the right-click context menu too.

```
<canvas oncontextmenu="return false" id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

And you can still read out the mouse clicks.

Edit:
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ovrrbhnr/1/

Comment: Of course, adding an event listener for the `contextmenu` event where you `preventDefault()` works the same way.

Comment: So e.preventDefault() won't work on mousedown for right click ?

Comment: e.preventDefault(); will work on mousedown and mouseup and disable the default event. But it would still allow the contextmenu.